# python/tastypie: authorization on a non-resource?

Tags: python, api, tastypie

Using tastypie for an API we have here.

So the main API class is:

```
from tastypie.api import Api

class TheAPI(Api):
  def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
     url(r"^(?P<api_name>%s)/reset/(?P<pk>\w+)%s$" % (self.api_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('reset'), name="api_reset"),
    ]
  def reset(self, request, **kwargs):
      #do the work
```

So far so good.
My problem lies in that I would like to use ApiAuthentication on this call. I don't want anybody be able to use the reset function (well there is a unique code in the URL but still).

But as this is not a Resource, I don't know how to do this. I tried adding a Meta class to this class, but it seems to be ignored.

The only other hack I could think of is inventing some `FakeResource` encapsulating this functionality, but that feels odd as it is not a resource.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hey,not sure if that code is alrigth. prepend_urls should return a list and in your code you are not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in extending the regular resource here and adding the `authorization` and `authentication` to the Meta class.

```
class BaseNonORMResource(Resource):

    class Meta:
        max_limit = None

        """
        (Using Tastypie's DjangoAuthorization which checks the permission a user has granted to them)
        and Tastypie's token based authentication approach
        """
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()

        '''
        Specify allowed_methods, list_allowed_methods or detail_allowed_methods in each SubResource
        e.g. allowed_methods = ['get']
        '''
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'delete', 'patch', 'put']
```

And then use it to define your endpoint

```
class TheAPI(BaseNonORMResource):
  def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
         url(r"^(?P<api_name>%s)/reset/(?P<pk>\w+)%s$" % (self.api_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('reset'), name="api_reset"),
    ]

  def reset(self, request, **kwargs):
      #do the work
```